# How to check that user has already logged in using Apache Shiro?

Tags: java, apache, shiro

The question is very simple. I'd like to restrict user access with same login from different machines/browsers: only one live user session is possible.

`Apache shiro` library is used for user authentification and managment.

Of course this could be done using simple synchornized maps and etc. But the question is: Has `Apache Shiro` special mechanisms for that or not?

Another variant of this question: how to reveice the list of all subjects who are logged in the system using `apache shiro`?

**UPD:**

To clarify my question. My desire is to have some code like this (I known, that there isn't such class exception, but the idea must be more clean):

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(login, password);
try {
    currentUser.login(token);
} catch (AlreadyAuthenticatedException aae) {
    errorMsg = "You should logoff on another machine!";
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built-in way. If you're in a webapp, add some `Map` object in the context to which you register `Principals` and compare against them. You'll have to have a session listener that removes them when the session is invalidated.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis And how actually I can implement this listener? I have no idea how I can catch this Shiro's event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shiro sessions are stored in `SessionDAO` with `sessionId` as keys. Without extra effort you cannot access a session by a principal (user name). However, you could extend `DefaultSecurityManager` and check all active sessions by `SessionDAO.getActiveSessions`.
The following codes could be a simple example (suppose you are not using `WebSubject`):

```
public class UniquePrincipalSecurityManager extends org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager {

    @Override
    public Subject login(Subject subject, AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

        String loginPrincipal = (String) token.getPrincipal();
        DefaultSessionManager sm = (DefaultSessionManager) getSessionManager();
        for (Session session : sm.getSessionDAO().getActiveSessions()) {
            SimplePrincipalCollection p = (SimplePrincipalCollection) session
                    .getAttribute(DefaultSubjectContext.PRINCIPALS_SESSION_KEY);
            if (p != null && loginPrincipal.equals(p.getPrimaryPrincipal())) {
                throw new AlreadyAuthenticatedException();
            }

        }
        return super.login(subject, token);
    }

}
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunatelly no: 1) I can not replace security manager; 2) `SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager()` returns proxy object which hasn't implementation of methods `getSessionDAO()`. it is actually `WebSecurityManager`; 3) yes, I have a deal with `WebObject`.

Comment: 1)You can change it by `SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager()`, or by spring configuration. 2) `getSessionDAO()` is in `DefaultSessionManager` which can be accessed only inside your extended `SecurityManager`. 3)You can change your custom `SecurityManager` to extend `DefaultWebSecurityManager` instead of `DefaultSecurityManager ` then.

Comment: Actually not: 1) I'm not using `spring`. 2) `SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager()` is not enough: inside `getSecurityManager()` class `ThreadContext` is used. It doesn't prevent early instantiation of proxy object of class `WebSecurityManager` and assigning it to internal `context`.

Comment: Well, actually thanks for idea. I had to replace my default `SecurityManager` class, reimplement `SessionManager` class and create my own `SessionDAO`. Buy it works!

Comment: Did you added some additional configuration into shiro.ini in order to run the code?

Comment: I think you should call ```super.login(subject, token);``` first to verify the credentials. Otherwise, a login with invalid password can also cause the exception, which is not desirable.