# Get list of all logged users from Apache Shiro

Tags: shiro

How I can get all logged in users as a list in Apache Shiro?

Can you give me some example?

Comment: Check the answer to [How to check that user has already logged in using Apache Shiro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095471/how-to-check-that-user-has-already-logged-in-using-apache-shiro)